# Problema para eliminar una carpeta con contenido java

Tags: java, netbeans

tengo el siguiente código.

```
public void eliminarCarpeta (){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La ruta de la carpeta a eliminar es: "+rutaFotos);
        File carpetaCreada = new File(rutaFotos);
        if (carpetaCreada.delete()==true) {
            System.out.println("Carpeta Eliminada");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No se pudo eliminar la carpeta");
        }
    }
```

Y mi problema puede ser sencillo pero no se como hacerlo. Resulta que utilizo este metodo para eliminar carpetas de "x" directorio y el inconveniente que estoy presentando es que cuando la carpeta tiene contenido, el metodo entra al else diciendome que no la pudo eliminar.

Cuando elimino el contenido de la carpeta (manualmente desde windows) y ejecuto nuevamente el metodo, este si logra eliminar la carpeta con exito. No se si estoy usando un metodo que solo sirve para eliminar carpetas vacias o si estoy ejecutandolo mal.

Lo unico que necesito es que el metodo elimine la carpeta de la ruta que le mande sea que tenga o no tenga contenido.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deberias recurrir a la recursividad.
Para ello, lo que buscas sería:

```
public static void eliminar(File f){

    if(f.isDirectory()){
        for(File f1 : f.listFiles()){
            eliminar(f1);
        }
    }
    f.delete();
}
```

Donde irias recorriendo los elementos dentro de los directorios y eliminando su contenido antes de eliminar el mismo elemento.